# Implement Facebooks ProfilePictureView

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, facebook

My Problem is following: Until yesterday i had successfully implemented Facebooks ProfilePictureView into my xml layouts. Then something weird happened with eclipse while I tried to clean my Project. 
Now eclipse says following to all my Facebook ProfilePictureViews:

Error: No resource identifier found for attribute preset_size in package my.package

Error: No resource identifier found for attribute is_cropped in package my.package

The xml looks like this:

```
<com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
                        android:id="@+id/profilePicFaceBook"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="170.0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        app:is_cropped="true"
                        app:preset_size="large" />
```

With the very outter Parent Relative Layout specified like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...

/>
```

In my Project Properties under Java Build Path i have FacebookSDK as a Project that is required to build the path.
ProfilePictureView is defined in that Project. 
All the other Facebook Sample Apps that use ProfilePictureView still work flawlessly. 
Again I have not changed anything in my code or my settings.

Ive tried manually adding the facebooksdk.jar file to my librarie dependencies -> Did not help
Ive tried copying all ProfilePictureView data into my own Project -> Did not help

How can i resolve this problem?
Im sure someone can help me.

Greetings, and thanks for the help already, Marvin.